# Probability: Prove that events are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning

I'm self-learning probability and struggle on the following task:

If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, prove that $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are also independent.

This is one of those cases where one event contains the other so they are always independent but I never came across to prove it.

Any clues? Please avoid answers in comments, because I cannot accept this way. Thanks!

Comment: If one event contains the other, they are always independent? I didn't know that. Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=$ heads on first coin toss and $B=$ heads on second toss.  They're independent.  Then
$$
\Pr(A\cup B) = \frac 3 4 \ne 1 = \Pr(A\cup B\mid A\cap B).
$$
So they're not independent.

If event $E$ "contains" event $F$, that means $\Pr(E\mid F)=1$.  If $\Pr(E)< 1$, then that conflicts with independence.  So the statement in the question that if one event contains the other then they're independent is very far from true.

Answer (score 2):

$A\cap B$ is never independent from $A\cup B$, unless either $A\cap B$ is negligible or $A\cup B$ is almost certain.

In fact, you should have $P(A\cap B)=P((A\cup B)\cap A\cap B)=P(A\cup B)P(A\cap B)$, hence $(P(A\cup B)-1)P(A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: The exceptions are, more simply, when P(A) or P(B) is 0 or 1.

Comment: @Did Under the further hypothesis of $A$ and $B$ being independent, yes. But, even though the problem has it, we don't really need to specialise the statement.

Comment: ?? You did "specialise the statement", in the first sentence of your post, and I merely rephrased the condition there, making it clearer (imho).

Comment: @Did What I mean is: "Let $A$, $B$ be measurable sets in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal E,P)$. Then $A\cup B$ is independent from $A\cap B$ if and only if $P(A\cup B)=1$ or $P(A\cap B)=0$." It is true that, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, the last condition is equivalent to one of the two events being either negligible or almost certain, but without requiring it we could have $B=\Omega\setminus A$. And it is clear that even the more general statement is sufficient to prove the claim in the OP to be false, since instances of independent events that fail the condition exist.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)+P(A')P(B)$$
$$P(\,(A \cup B)\cap (A \cap B)\,)=P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$
$$P(A \cup B)P(A\cap B)=P(A)^2P(B)+P(A')P(A)P(B)^2=P(A)P(B)(\,P(A)+P(A')P(B)\,)$$
therefore if $P(A)\ne 0$ , $P(A)\ne1$, $P(B)\ne 0$, and $P(B)\ne1$, then
$$P(\,(A \cup B)\cap (A \cap B)\,)\ne P(A \cup B)P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Except if P(A) or P(B) is 0 or 1, that is.